# Calculating time periods for users in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database table something like:

```
ID  | User_ID   | User_State    | State_Datetime
---
1   | 1     | Login     | 2015-02-01 09:00:00
---
2   | 1     | Work      | 2015-02-01 09:05:00
---
3   | 1     | Break     | 2015-02-01 12:00:00
---
4   | 1     | Work      | 2015-02-01 13:10:00
---
5   | 1     | Logout    | 2015-02-01 18:00:00
---
6   | 2     | Login     | 2015-02-01 10:09:00
---
7   | 2     | Work      | 2015-02-01 10:50:00
---
8   | 2     | break     | 2015-02-01 13:10:00
---
9   | 2     | Work      | 2015-02-01 14:00:00
---
10  | 2     | Logout    | 2015-02-01 20:30:00
---
```

I want to find out how much **break time**, **work time** and **total login time** (logout - login) each user has utilized every day. A break time would be when break starts till next User_State is assigned, and work time would be when work starts till next User_State is assigned.

Is there any single query which can help me get this information?

I need result as:

```
 User_ID    | State | Date  | State_Time (HH:MM:SS) 
1   | Login | 2015-02-01    | 09:00:00 (this is logout time - login time)
1   | Work  | 2015-02-01    | 07:45:00 (this is time from work to break and work to logout etc)
1   | Break | 2015-02-01    | 01:10:00 (this is time from break to work)    
2   | Login | 2015-02-01    | 10:21:00 
2   | Work  | 2015-02-01    | 06:50:00  
2   | Break | 2015-02-01    | 00:50:00
```

It's like employee database for their office hours and details on work and break. Login will be the first state in each day for employee and logout would be the last one. Break status can be more than once in a day and so is work.

every state ends when new state is marked.
So when WORK is marked, WORK starts; if BREAK is marked after WORK, WORK ends and BREAK starts; if again WORK is marked, BREAK ends and WORK starts. Ideally, nothing should be marked after LOGOUT.

Comment: do you need it calculated by pair? only `logout - login`? so `work - login` and `break - work` - doesn't work? you have only two pairs that must be calculated?

Comment: your update is pretty useless. the meaning of each record is clear - that i sLOG of some events. your proble and my question is about rules! so when I have started WORK with event - which events must call the end of WORK proccess? LOGIN? LOGOUT? BREAK? ANY? new WORK? the same question whe break starts it is clear but if after break started first record is LOGIN - does it mean that break finished?? or not? you must write ALL rules.

Comment: so if Login must be only one per day and only first in the mornign - write it as pre-requerments. if **login** could be finished only once per day and only by **logout** event - write it down as pre-requirements, and so on and so on

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT *, t.state_end 
FROM log_table 
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT id, 
    state_datetime END AS state_end,
    @prev_id  AS prev_id,
    @prev_id := id AS next_id
FROM
log_table
ORDER BY user_id, state_datetime
) as t
ON log_table.id = t.prev_id
```

Comment: ? :-) as what? just post expected result in your question post

Comment: I need result as ---- User_ID | State  | Date   | State_Time (HH:MM:SS)
1  | Login  | 2015-02-01  | 09:00:00
1  | Work  | 2015-02-01  | 07:45:00 
1  | Break  | 2015-02-01  | 01:10:00 
2  | Login  | 2015-02-01  | 10:21:00
2  | Work  | 2015-02-01  | 06:50:00 
2  | Break  | 2015-02-01  | 00:50:00 

like that…

Comment: so in result query  state **logout** will never appear? and you mean just one login per day? and/or one break per day? can be the row of -login->logout ? with no work? could be **work** the first state before **login** or **logout**? could **logout** be the first state in the morning?

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex for the help.. yes, only one login and one logout per day. but break and work states can be repeated (actually there could be more states too).

Comment: you can describe all that in the body of your post. the problem is not query. the problem is your requirements. that you didn't really include in your post

Comment: it's like employee database for their office hours and details on work and break. login will be the first state in each day for employee and logout would be the last one. break status can be more than once in a day and so is work. yes, there can be one row of login->logout for entire time an employee is logged in. Does this help.

Comment: don't tell me the story :-) put REQUIREMENTS in your post